# What is an elegant way to replace an element of an array based on a match criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the following logic to update a list item based on a criteria.

```
def update_orders_list(order)
  @orders.delete_if{|o| o.id == order.id}
  @orders << order
end
```

Ideally, I would have preferred these approaches:

```
array.find_and_replace(obj) { |o| conditon }
```

OR

```
idx = array.find_index_of { |o| condition }
array[idx] = obj
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 1.8.7, [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#method-i-index) accepts a block.  So your last example should work just fine with a minor tweak.

```
idx = array.index { |o| condition }
array[idx] = obj
```

Comment: I didn't find this in Array documentation as I was looking at 1.8.6 documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
array.map { |o| if condition(o) then obj else o }
```

maybe?

Comment: Yep this should do it.  Though `condition(o) ? obj : o` might be a little more standard.  You could even extend the `Array` class with a `find_and_replace` method to make it work just like your psuedo code.

Comment: maybe map! to make it in-place?